# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have include a jar file in my android project. Inside the jar file there is a class `OverlayView` in a package name `android.widget`. I can import the class into my `Test.java` file by `import android.widget.OverlayView;` and call the method `init()`. After these I can compile successfully. But while running the app it throws an exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.OverlayView.init
```

I didnt get class definition error

Answer (score 0):

Your library contains android.widget? There is already a package with android.widget as its name. My guess is that it's conflicting with your library. Try deleting the import statements, by this time you should get an error because you deleted the import. Place your cursor in the method that has error then wait for the import suggestion to pop out, then alt+enter to import package. See if it is conflicting with the default android.widget package.

Comment: No conflict occurring . It imports normally as `import android.widget.OverlayView;`